# How can I share my USB internet USB0 to the RPI on my LAN connected via ETH0

Tags: networking, usb, lan, ethernet, internet-sharing

Laptop = linux

RPI = raspbian

USB internet = mobile tethering

I can have both devices on my computer. If I try and ping i get the following:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=43 time=120 ms    //USB0 connected ETHO     disconnected
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=43 time=78.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=43 time=88.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=43 time=65.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=5 ttl=43 time=252 ms
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable   //USB0 connected ETHO connected
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.247 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=14 ttl=43 time=58.5 ms  //USB0 connected ETHO disconnected
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=15 ttl=43 time=56.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=16 ttl=43 time=74.4 ms
```

How can I have it so that when both are connected I can still ping to the internet and follow up would be access that internet from my RPI.

Comment: Just to clarify, USB internet = wifi? or Wired? Raspberry Pi already have its own LAN port (eth0) - and also what OS are you running? Raspbian?

Comment: @Darius USB internet = tethering from mobile and running linux on laptop and raspbian rpi

Comment: I have similar problem ... http://superuser.com/questions/1179778/how-to-play-pc-media-on-tv-via-dlna Can you halp me...

Comment: I have similar problem ... http://superuser.com/questions/1179778/how-to-play-pc-media-on-tv-via-dlna Can you halp me...