# How to play pc media on TV via DLNA

Tags: networking, android, lan, dlna

I have following setup.... Pc with 2 usb and 1 ethernet port... Also I have win10 and linux mint on that pc..

Samsung on8 android 6(jio 4g sim) with Wi-Fi hotspot and data(internet)....ON.....

Samsung wave y (BADA os) with Wi-Fi On and connected to that hotspot... And also connected to pc via usb.. with 'usb tethering'...

Sony bravia led tv connected to same Wi-Fi hotspot..

Tablet (android) connected to same hotspot

Now I can Access Internet on pc.... Access internet (mainly YouTube) on Sony Tv Access internet on tablet. I also have installed Bubble UPnP on both android device.... And I can play media OF my Samsung On8 to Sony TV

As well as media OF tablet to Sony Tv.. Even Wave y (BADA os )has All share to play media to Sony TV on these setup...

Further I have xplore installed on both android.... It has feature called Wi-Fi file sharing ....you have to turn on Wi-Fi file server on one xplore and you can access its files on xplore on another device ... And when I turn on Wi-Fi file sharing it displays IP address and port number ... And with it I can access files on Chrome on myPC....

I hope you will understand this setup....

Now what I couldn't do is ....

I can't play media stored in my PC directly to Sony TV...with any UPNP app .....(can't do stream media from WMP or Vlc,or play to device)

I can not access shared folders and files of pc from my android phone or tablet..(in xplore and es file manager there is a tool called 'Lan' with which you can access shared folders on network.('you'.. may be.. can but I cant))

(My suspect:

Is this because I have used USB port instead of standard Ethernet port to connect to network?

If it is then why there is network connected icon is displayed in sys tray... Why internet Is accessible on PC..

Additional info: ifconfig displays inet address in usb0 interface...not in eth0. And i can view Sony bravia's dlna profile file (.xml) On chrome on my PC.. . ) I have these facilities (as well as limitation)on both Windows 10 and Linux Mint....

My questions are :

1: how can I access shared folder of pc running mint or windows from android device on this setup?

2: how to play media stores on pc to Sony TV directly ?

I don't want to use direct usb cable because if I do so my android' s touch goes CRAZY......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Wave Y is having two interface.
wlan0 used for Wifi connection and Wifi Hotspot.
rndis0 used for USB Tethering to PC
when you use USB Tethering to PC,it will be displayed as usb0 interface on PC which acts like eth0.
So Wave Y is acting as router between PC and Galaxy On8. 
Well These type of phone are not as powerful as compared to standard routers.
For internet access it forwards PC's request to Galaxy On8 and Galaxy on8 will reply via SAME PATH.
A ping from PC to Galaxy On8 will be successful,
but reverse is not possible.
because Wave Y will not forward communication **FROM** outside world (yes,your WiFi network too is considered as outsider)  **TO** PC for security reason.
So PC is not able to scanned from Your WiFi Network.
If You have rooted Android Device then ,altering iptables will allow bidirectional communication from PC to Galaxy On8 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use DLNA applications available for your PC/Mac.
You can create a media server on your PC by using applications like:

1. [Plex](http://plex.tv/)
2. [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/)
3. And many more.. [Here](http://alternativeto.net/software/plex/)

Once setup, you can simply browse on the media server using your TV on the same network or via a media device such as Xbox or PlayStation and can stream media.

Plex even provide support for android and windows devices to access media, and even the remote streaming support if you have a solid internet connectivity.

And I have mentioned only few to get you started, there are many options available.

Comment: I tried plex .But my tv isn't detecting that..in Windows 10 Windows media player is not showing bubble UPNP server of either of my android devices ,however they both can detect each other's media server...but when I type full address(obtained from bubble UPNP app on android phone) of some video in chrome on my PC.,chrome starts playing that video!

Comment: Do a little experiment
Things needed

1. A pc (laptop with WiFi would be better).
2. Two Android device with data cable
3. Xplore file manager on android.

First create hotspot on android1 ,connect pc and android2 to it.
Share file/folder in pc
Access these files on android2 in xplore app in LAN
if you can then this is okay.
Now turn off wifi of just pc,(this leaves android1 with hot spot and android2 connected to it)
And connect android2 to pc via data cable and turn on USB Tethering.
Now try to access shared  folder/files of pc on xplore on android1.
Share the result !

Comment: This is more like 'connection not established...' type rather than lack of app....